# react-native-tus-client No such file or directory Error

Tags: android, react-native

I want to use tus-client to upload my videos on a remote endpoint. but after choosing a video from my android device and when I start upload it shows an Error which says
Failed because: Error: file:/storage/emulated/0/Movies/c5326f6c-dc42-4eb0-97c8-040233f08352.mp4 (No such file or directory)
is there any solution for that or could you help me to find the right way for uploading my files?
best regards;

my react-native version is 0.60.6
the video uri is like: file:/storage/emulated/0/Movies/c5326f6c-dc42-4eb0-97c8-040233f08352.mp4
and the way I'm trying to send my files is:

```
let uploadOptions = {
"url": my_EndpointUri,
"authorization": ${authorization_key},
"acceptLanguage": 'en',
"uuid": "salam"//ImageUri.name + ImageUri.size + ImageUri.lastModified,
};
const upload = new Upload(ImageUri, {
fingerprint: () => {
return uploadOptions.uuid;
},
resume: true,
chunkSize: 1048576, // 1MB
retryDelays: [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500],
endpoint: uploadOptions.url,
headers: {
'Authorization': uploadOptions.authorization,
'Accept-Language': uploadOptions.acceptLanguage,
},
metadata: {
filename: "video.mp4",
filetype: "video/mp4"
},
onError: function (error) {
console.log("Failed because: " + error)
},
onProgress: function (bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
var percentage = (bytesUploaded / bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2)
console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, percentage + "%")
},
onSuccess: function () {
console.log("Download %s from %s", upload.file.name, upload.url)
}
});
await upload.start();
}
```

**Update**: Finally I used reactjs-tus-client instead of reactnative and now it works properly.